# Add an edge label with Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

How can I add a label on an edge using Cytoscape.js?

Answer (score 50):

Map the `label` style property to a data field:

e.g. in the stylesheet on init

```
...

{
  selector: 'edge',
  style: {
    'label': 'data(label)' // maps to data.label
  }
} 

...
```

http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/#style/properties

Older versions use `content:` in place of `label:`.  Newer versions of 2.x allow `label` and also `content` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hey maxkfranz can u tell i have node id which i got from some text box how can i select that node in graph by triggering any event. I want to do something like basic code of click fucntion in cytoscape graph works but my user will enter node id in textfield.

Comment: `label` does not work for me although I use cytoscapejs 2.4.9. `content` works, indeed.

Comment: @maxkfranz is there a way to handle if label is null??