# label on edges with cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cytoscape.js

I am learning [cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/). I want to create graph with nodes and edges. Graph will be created using run-time data. I want to add labels on edges based on data values. Each label will have different value. Can anyone help me with some detailed example for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172427/add-an-edge-label-with-cytoscape-js#

I think that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some data field `foo`, use `content: data(foo)` in your style to map `foo` to the label of the elements matched by your selector.