# Affix the cytoscape.js edge label to the edge

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js

This is somewhat of a follow on to this question (I'm piggybacking here):

[Add an edge label with Cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172427/add-an-edge-label-with-cytoscape-js#)

This allows you to add a label to the edge, but the labels are always horizontal regardless of the edge's actual position. Is there anyway to bind the label itself to the edge so that when the edge repositions, the label rotates with it?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, and I would be hesitant to add a feature like that because it makes the text harder to read for users.  It also wouldn't really be possible for bezier edges without skewing the text -- making legibility even worse.

Do you have a specific usecase that requires labels like this.  Would you please describe it?

Edit:

Also see [#714](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/714).  Rui Cheng is implementing a feature like this.

Comment: Well, from what I understood, [this](http://codio.io/gpublio/GAT-HTML5/index_v01.html) is the problem that he's talking about. This overposition on edge's labels is bothering.

Answer (score 0):

I made patch for cytoscape, maybe it will be helpfull for you.

Link to patched buld version: [cytoscape-2.3.4-patched.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-4pHBlNSVfcTNUZktfMndEZ00/view?usp=sharing)

Link to patch for builded js file version 2.3.4: [cytoscape-2.3.4.patch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4-4pHBlNSVfYjVYeHNHWnRpWVU/view?usp=sharing)

Please, ask your questions if you have.